# How to wrap text of chart title in chart.js by providing the text value of type string?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The chart title gets squashed when the title is bit long as compared to the width of the chart(snap below), so is there any option by which the chart title can enter into next line.

```
plugins: {
               title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In rutrum leo ut tellus tempor, venenatis vulputate nisl sagittis. Morbi id fringilla purus. Etiam imperdiet ipsum.',
                  color: 'navy',
                  position: 'top',
                  align: 'center',
                  font: {
                     weight: 'bold'
                  },
                  padding: 8,
               }
            }
```

[Chart with Title squashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW9F2.png)

Note: The **text** property must be of string type, not string of array type.

I expect the chart title to not getting squashed and enter into next line when the length of the title is longer than the width of the chart, something like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55JDH.png)